# Different class variables and usage

Tags: python, global-variables, class-variables

In a class in Python there are several ways to assign something to a variable.
I always don't know where I should do it, what is the difference in usage and in which scenario should I use a distinct variant.

```
class Class(object):
    NUMBER = 31415
    foo = 'FOO'

    def __init__(self):
        self.foobar = 'foobar'
```

Comment: This question is very broad :/

Comment: what's about the constants, are they really constant, so can't they be changed?

Comment: you're definition of `__init__` has a typo.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Class variables are shared between all instances of a class. That turns out to be pretty self-explanatory. Instance variables however are local to each instantiated object.

Here's an example, first we instantiate a bunch of classes.

```
In [19]: classes = [Class() for _ in range(5)]

In [20]: classes
Out[20]: 
[<__main__.Class at 0x20bb290>,
 <__main__.Class at 0x20bb2d0>,
 <__main__.Class at 0x20bb310>,
 <__main__.Class at 0x20bb350>,
 <__main__.Class at 0x20bb4d0>]
```

And then we change the `NUMBER`-variable of `Class`

```
In [21]: Class.NUMBER = "Hah!"

In [22]: print [x.NUMBER for x in classes]
['Hah!', 'Hah!', 'Hah!', 'Hah!', 'Hah!']
```

However, once you've instantiated the objects, you can change `x.NUMBER`, and once you do the change *is* local to that object. I understand this can be quite confusing.

Where as we cannot even touch the `foobar`-value yet, as it does not exist before the object is instantiated:

```
In [23]: Class.foobar
---------------------------------------------------------------------------
AttributeError                            Traceback (most recent call last)
<ipython-input-23-c680e41ebe07> in <module>()
----> 1 Class.foobar

AttributeError: type object 'Class' has no attribute 'foobar'
```

This has nothing to do with whether or not the class attributes are upper or lowercase. We can just as well access `Class.foo`. The point is that everything before the `__init__` exists *before* that class is instantiated to an object. Once that class is instantiated as an object, the object will have the *instance* attributes, namely `obj.foobar`.

Comment: ok, so the uppercase constant is just a convention. we can change the value directly in python..

Comment: The case doesn't matter.

Comment: So there are no constants in python at all??

Comment: Not really, you can pretty much access anything from anywhere. There are some conventions (like double underscores) which cause some mangling of variable names during import but *everything* is accessible.

Comment: And there is no difference in calling a variable with the instance. So  if i have an instance `x = Class()`, i will call `x.NUMBER` and `x.foobar` the same way

Answer (score 1):

Class variable will has same value for 2 instances but instance variable will have difference value for each instances.